# Quickblox Android : Get status of connection request sent

Tags: android, request, connection, quickblox

I am using Quickblox for chatting application in Android.
I have sent friend / connection request to any person I want status of that request i.e. weather it is accepted or pending?

```
QBRoster chatRoster;
chatRoster.subscribe(userID);
```

Reference : [http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Contact_list](http://Quickblox%20contacts%20guide)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for the question is

```
QBRoster roster;
Collection<QBRosterEntry> entries
QBRosterEntry rosterEntry = roster.getEntry(holder.userid);
boolean isSubscribedToUser = rosterEntry.getType() == RosterPacket.ItemType.from;
boolean isBothSubscribed = rosterEntry.getType() == RosterPacket.ItemType.both;
QBPresence presence;
for (QBRosterEntry entry : entries)
{
    presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUserId());
    System.out.println(entry.getStatus());//online/offline
    System.out.println(presence.getType().name());
}
boolean ispendingFreindRequest=RosterPacket.ItemStatus.subscribe.equals(rosterEntry.getStatus());
String stausRelationaship=RosterPacket.ItemType.none.name();
```

Note roster should not be null.
Initialize it after successfully creating session and user login.